# drupal 7 services rest not returning json

Tags: json, drupal, drupal-7

I have created a webservice successfully and I can call it , but it returns XML always. I tried adding .json at the end of the url and 'accept: application/json' header, but when I call these, it returns blank with a 200 response.

The configuration done (admin/structure/services) is:

- edit tab: created a rest service with "path to endpoint" = loginapi  & debug enabled
- server tab: response formatters & parsing are all checked (including json)
- resources tab: everything under user is checked without any alias
- domain.com/loginapi/user/login --> this works perfect & I can login and returns xml, adding .json (login.json) returns nothing

How can I make this work please? I've went through all docs & examples, but none work for me

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check your server configuration is as follow: [Services API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7AjP.png)

Then validate your endpoint with `curl -H "Accept: application/json" -i https://your.domain/endpoint`. Return header should have `Content-Type: application/json`

Answer (score 0):

To return JSON from Drupal, check the drupal_json_output function (It sets the HTTP Content-Type header for you). Pro Tip: If your endpoint is defined through hook_menu, you can add `'delivery callback' => 'drupal_json_output'` to your menu item to tell Drupal that your page callback's return value should be converted to output.

However, this doesn't work if your menu item has an 'access callback'. For some technical reason inside of Drupal core, a 3 gets returned instead of a 403 status if the access check fails. I wish I could remember how I solved that when I first figured it out half a year ago :-(